# Setting cookies other than standard

Tags: php, cookies, smf-forum

I am trying to modify a theme template to set some new cookies with php. My code works on a non-SMF test page but it stops the page from loading when I put it into the index.template.php file.

The cookies are set in php and the whole code basically attempts to get the POST data from a new form on the page.

As I mentioned, on a simple test page I can put my php code above the  HTML and it works fine.

Is there something special about the way SMF handles cookies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you mean by SMF.

Comment: SMF = Simple Machines Forums http://www.simplemachines.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, they've probably already send out headers.

You can't set a cookie once headers have been sent.

==== Update ====

If you want to use jQuery see this:

[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks. Can I set cookies with jQuery if php has already sent headers and set some other cookies?